# Travis and Firebase: deploy only changed functions

Tags: firebase, deployment, travis-ci, google-cloud-functions

I'm using Travis to automatically deploy my Firebase hosted website and cloud functions as I push to GitHub, as detailed [here](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/firebase/). However, even for my small website with a limited amount of cloud functions, deploying all of the functions takes quite a long time. Were I deploying manually, I would be able to use `--only` to specify precisely those functions that I actually changed. Is there a way to make this information available to Travis, so that only the necessary functions are rebuilt?

Answer (score 9):

https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=iyGHW4UQ_Ts

min 30 and following

This guy solves the problem by copying all functions to a cloud bucket and then making a diff for every file. This works well if all your logic is in one file. But this is not what you want for larger projects. For my own project i used webpack to create one file for each function that includes the imports. then i generate a md5 hash for that file and save it to a functions-lock.json. with the next run i can easily check against the old hash value and only deploy the changed functions. The ci should manage the state of the lock file by uploading it to the cloud or doing some git magic

Comment: I like this approach. This answer could be improved by adding more details on how you accomplish this: I'm thinking examples/snippets from webpack, scripts, buildfile.

Thanks!

Comment: A blog post or article on your approach would be awesome!

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately this isn't going to be simple to do -- the Firebase CLI deploys all of your functions because it's next-to-impossible to just analyze the code and figure out which functions are impacted (since you can require other files, you might have updated dependencies but no files changed, etc.).

One thing I can think of that might be a hack would be to have named branches for functions or groups of functions. Then you could `git push` to the branch of the specific function you want to deploy, and have a script that uses the branch name as a signal to pass the `--only functions:<fnName>` to the `firebase deploy` command. That's not the most glamorous solution, but, depending on how much this bugs you, it might help.

Comment: Couldn't the developer identify the modified functions in the commit comment? You could script the same deploy from the commit log then.

Comment: I thought about that, but a push may contain multiple commits, and it feels like it's getting increasingly complex/risky to try to figure out "do a log since last deploy, scrape function names out of all commits, deploy that".

Comment: It sounds incredibly cool if it'd do that, but indeed increasingly risky. Good call!

Comment: @MichaelBleigh I know this was like 5 years ago now, but... would it be possible to instead compare a hash of the contents of what is uploaded for the function deploy?

If the hash is the same... leave it alone?

Comment: @HenrikJoreteg actually...yes! We have recently been working on what we call "no-op deploys" which works by hashing and comparing the uploaded source. Coming very soon (as of Sep 2022) :)

Comment: @MichaelBleigh that'd be very helpful!

Comment: As of [v11.13.0](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/releases/tag/v11.13.0) of the Firebase CLI functions are not deployed if there is no change to any file in the functions directory. You can use this with the new [codebases](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/organize-functions#organize_functions_in_codebases) feature for more granular groupings.

Answer (score 2):

So this is a bit late but the long deployment times have bothered us for a while now.

Our solution is based on CircleCI but it should be possible to adapt.

First we get all changed files in the last merged PR for our branch with

```
git log -m -1 --name-only --pretty="format:" ${process.env.CIRCLE_SHA1}
```

CIRCLE_SHA1 is the SHA of the last merge commit, i.e featurebranch -> master

Then we get all the function filenames from our /functions/ directory and use

[madge](https://www.npmjs.com/package/madge) to generate an array of all the dependencies those functions have.

Next we go trough all changed files that we got from git and check if their filename is part of the dependency array for a sepcific cloud function, if so we add the cloudfunction to another array.

once this is done we pretty much have an array from all cloudfunctions that have been affected by the change of a specific file that we now can map to their actual cloud function names for deployment.

Now instead of always deploying 75 cloudfunctions which takes 45 minutes we only deploy maybe 20.